# How to enable Genymotion emulator to use the WIFI internet the host is using

Tags: android, oracle, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

The app I am running on Genymotion emulator needs internet. The internet does not seem to work on the Genymotion emulator. I tried to confirm this by opening the browser, and this is what I got:

[image]

I am running Windows 7 on my laptop and using the Wifi internet. I opened Oracle VM Virtual box, navigated to Settings > Network, and the following two images show what I see there:

[image]

**So how do I enable the emulator to use the internet from my computer?**

***Note:*** *Please tell me in layman terms. I saw articles and questions talking in terms of IP addresses and other things which are strange for me.*

---

***EDIT 1:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you turned on the wifi in the genymotion device?

Comment: @Bhargav Umm no, how do I do that? I clicked the icon which looks like the wifi on the right side, but it says it is not available in the free version (I am adding the screenshots in the question). Does this mean I can not use the wifi internet in the free version?

Comment: no not that one lol. goto settings in the device and turn on the device wifi, in the android OS. You haven't mentioned it in your post I'm just covering the basic solutions here.

Comment: @Bhargav Thank you so very much. This solved my problem. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it, will be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

goto settings in the device and turn on the device wifi, in the android OS. You haven't mentioned it in your post I'm just covering the basic solutions here.

Comment: i enable wifi from settings but the same error appear "Network feature is not available in free personal version"

Comment: @AmalKronz in the latest version of genymotion the network feature is removed I think

Comment: @Bhargav I'm using `v2.10.0` (_last version at the time of writing_) and can connect to internet without any problem.

Answer (score 5):

Simply choose the Host-only Adapter for Adapter 1 and NAT for Adapter 2.
Make sure the cable-connected is selected(ticked).
Host-only can be used to create a network containing the host and a set of virtual machines, without the need for the host's physical network interface. Instead, a virtual network interface (similar to a loopback interface) is created on the host, providing connectivity among virtual machines and the host.

This works for me.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I have Host-only Adapter selected for Adapter 1, and NAT for Adapter 2. Cable-connected is also checked. But still not working for me. I can not turn on the wifi because I am using the free version (I just added the screenshots in the question, you can see them). Is this a reason?

Comment: @Solace I use the free version as well so it should not be the reason. Have you signed in for the Genymotion?

Comment: @Solace Here is my configuration for the Adapter, you could try it: Enable Network Adapter(checked), Attached to(Host-only Adapter), Adapter Type(Paravirtualized Network(virtio-net)), Promiscuous Mode(Deny),Cable Connected(checked).      Another possible reason could be your VirtualBox version does not match the Genymotion emulator(it happens sometimes).

Comment: Yes I am signed in. Are you able to turn on the wifi on the device by clicking on the icon I have shown in the second last screenshot in the question?

Comment: "Another possible reason could be your VirtualBox version does not match the Genymotion emulator(it happens sometimes)" - I downloaded the Genymotion and the virtual box bundled together from their website.

Comment: My configuration is just the same. BUT! See the section titled "What is the best network configuration for an optimal use of Genymotion?" [on this page.](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support#faq)

Comment: @Solace Then check your computer network settings, if this configuration works there suppose to be a fake adapter in your computer network. It may be blocked by your computer's network setting.

Comment: Turning on the wifi in Settings of the device solved the problem. Thank you very much for your time and answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try just turning on the WiFi in GenyMotion and selecting the WiredSSID.

[image: Click to view Genymotion screenshot.]

I know this question been answered, but thought a picture would be easy to understand. Hope it helps.

Comment: @David Makogon : Thanks for editing the answer. I had to include the image link instead of the image because I needed 10 reputation on the site to embed images.

Answer (score 1):

No of the above solution worked for me, I fixed the issue by changing the ip address settings on the adapter by going to File >> Preferences >> Network in VirtualBox:

Adapter
IP: 192.168.217.2
Network Mask: 255.255.255.0

DHCP Server
Server Address: 192.168.217.100
Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
Lower Address Bound: 192.168.217.101
Upper Address Bound: 192.168.217.254

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings >> Network in VirtualBox: adapter 1 >> advanced >> MAC address button generated new mac address.

I hope it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your PC `Ethernet` or `WIFI` Settings and change the Adapter `Preferred DNS Server` to `8.8.8.8`

Answer (score -1):

In **Genymotion**,
Go to **settings** of your device and make sure **adapter** that you have selected is **NAT(Default)** not **bridged** or anything..
Now, make sure that your PC is connected to Internet...
It will work , most probably