# Is it possible to emulate Wi-Fi connection with no internet connection in it in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to test my app in conditions when device is connected to Wi-Fi AP but without internet available in it. Is there any way to recreate these conditions in default Android Emulator?

Comment: Elaborate More...Specify Properly

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is disconnect from network and connect again you might try swtching airplane mode:

**ON**

```
.\adb -e shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1; .\adb -e shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true
```

**OFF**

```
.\adb -e shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0; .\adb -e shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state false
```

This is all that can be done with standard Android Emulator. [WiFi is not supported](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#limitations) on it.
However you might try using Genymotion emulator, as it has [WiFi functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132821/how-to-enable-genymotion-emulator-to-use-the-wifi-internet-the-host-is-using)

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off the internet on your host system, your emulator should still remain connected to the emulated WiFi (whilst not having access to the internet, of course)

Comment: That's what I want to recreate in Android Emulator